# How do I prevent infinite recursion in X11 start-up process?

Tags: mac, shell, xorg

I wasn't able to run X11 or Terminal after rebooting my Mac. After digging around, I got them to work when I commented-out this line in my .cshrc:

```
xset b off
```

It appears that `xset` will attempt to launch X11 if it isn't running already, and since X11 will launch the default shell through `xterm` and thus encounter the `xset` line above, we will have an infinite loop.

I would like to keep the above line in my .cshrc. Is there a way to prevent X11 from launching itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands used during the initialization of the X server should be placed in `~/.xinitrc`. You may want to copy (or source) the default found at `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, copy and paste the following

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/.X11-unix
```

then force-close x11. It should have stopped.

Comment: As I explained in the question, the culprit was that X11 was being launched by the `xset` command in my `.cshrc`. Ignacio pointed-out that the command should be in `.xinitrc`. The issue has nothing to do with the presence of a temporary file.